# Combine cellfun and subs in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, substitution, cell-array

I have some values stored in a matrix, e.g.

```
Matrix = [1,4,6]
```

and a cell array, such as:

```
CellArray{1} = [0,0,1,0]
...
CellArray{4} = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
...
CellArray{6} = [0,0,1,1,1,0]
```

For each element of the Matrix in CellArray, i.e. CellArray{Matrix(1:end)}, I want to substitute the ones with zeros. So far, I've thought of:

```
[Output] = cellfun(@(x) subs(x,1,0),{CellArray{Matrix}},'UniformOutput',false)
```

though, the ouput is not as I wanted...

Comment: `subs` is not what you think it is, try `subs([2,3,4],2,1)`. What you're doing should probably work, but I'm not sure how an anonymous function will do that replacement for you

Comment: @AndrasDeak, I think it is, as in your example array, all 2's are substituted with a 1 and the result is `[1,3,4]`

Comment: For me it's `ans = 2     3     4` using the symbolic math toolbox... Is this a newer built-in, or a custom function of yours?

Comment: @AndrasDeak I'm reffering to [link] http://se.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html

Comment: OK, one option is `@(x) str2double(regexprep(num2str(x),'1','0'))` :D Also, I also mean the [same subs](http://se.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html), but it doesn't change the vector in my example. I'm using R2012b. What about you?

Comment: @AndrasDeak 2015b :)

Comment: OK. Then we've found a difference:) So: what *does* it return if not what you want? As I see it, it should return the substituted subset of `CellArray`. Are you missing the non-substituted elements? Or is there some other issue?

Comment: @AndrasDeak the function works fine when run for each individual part of x, but returns a cell-array with `sym` values when run as a whole. The `@(x) subs(x,1,0)` returns the same as your posted option.

Comment: You should be able to cast to a numeric array with `@(x) double(subs(x,1,0))`, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: @AndrasDeak PERFECT! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. But symbolic math is *so* slow that my half-joking string manipulation version might outperform it still. I suggest some timing checks.

Comment: @AndrasDeak thanks, I'll keep that in mind - and should maybe try to figure out why it changes to symbolic in the first place...

Comment: It changes to symbolic because it's a symbolic function designed to work on symbolic arrays. It's a small wonder that it works properly for purely numeric arrays (and as you saw, it doesn't work for me). It's a strongly unintended use of the function, so you should expect some oddities.

Comment: @AndrasDeak thanks again :)

Comment: Anytime. I've considered your problem, and decided that it might be of use to future readers. So I've added an answer. I've also fixed a syntax error in your question (and retagged with [cell-array]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the example suggests that `CellArray` only contains vectors with `0`s and `1`s (and the question does not specify the opposite), may I suggest

```
Output = cellfun(@(x)zeros(1, numel(x)), CellArray(Matrix), 'uniformoutput', 0)
```

which really just replaces the entry with a zero vector of appropriate length.

Comment: In my case, where only `0`s and `1`s exist, this answer is perfect. Removes the `subs` problem and is easy to understand/implement.

Answer (score 1):

As we've settled in comments, the problem is that `subs()` is part of the Symbolic Math Toolbox, and it returns symbolic arrays. Note that this function won't even substitute into a numeric array in R2012b, but you are using R2015b, where it does.

So the solution is to explicitly cast to a numeric array in your `cellfun`:

```
[Output] = cellfun(@(x) double(subs(x,1,0)),{CellArray{Matrix}},'UniformOutput',false);
```

or, since symbolic math is really slow, maybe a similarly inefficient string-based solution might be competitive:

```
oddrep = @(x) str2num(regexprep(num2str(x),'1','0'));
[Output] = cellfun(oddrep,{CellArray{Matrix}},'UniformOutput',false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Jocular answer aside, there is the `subsasgn` way to do it:

```
Output = cellfun(@(x)subsasgn(x, struct('type','()', 'subs',{{find(x==1)}}), 0), CellArray(Matrix), 'uniformoutput', 0);
```

This works correctly for cases where there are non-zero and non-one entries. It should also be faster then either the string or symbolic methods.
And it should be possible to modify this so entries of `CellArray` are modified in place.

**Edit:**

The following indigestible one-liner replaces the elements of `CellArray` indicated by `Matrix` in place:

```
CellArray = subsasgn(CellArray, struct('type', '()', 'subs', {{Matrix}}), cellfun(@(x)subsasgn(x, struct('type','()', 'subs',{{find(x==1)}}), 0), CellArray(Matrix), 'uniformoutput', 0))
```